# Show and store different date formats on AngularJS Directive

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel, date

I have a directive that I use to display a datepicker on date inputs. It works well when I use this date format:

> yy-mm-dd

(I store that date on MySQL). The problem is that I need to display the date on a different format

> dd-mm-yy

But it doesn't play well with MySQL (it stores it like this: 0000-00-00).

This is the directive I'm using:

```
.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function (date) {
                        scope.date = date;
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to use a date format to show it to the user and another to actually use it on my model?

Comment: As long as the you have a date object in the model you can use the in built angularjs [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to display it in whatever format you like. You can use the same filter to to format the date in your controller before posting it to the backend that saves it to the database.

Comment: you can use date filter

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use filter for this ? Let me show you :

Apply it in your controller like this :

```
$scope.selectedDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.dateFilter), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Or directly use it in a view like this and notice the different format :

```
Here are the built-in localize formats:

{{ today | date:'medium' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 12:09:02 PM -->
{{ today | date:'short' }} <!-- 8/9/13 12:09 PM -->
{{ today | date:'fullDate' }} <!-- Thursday, August 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'longDate' }} <!-- August 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'mediumDate' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'shortDate' }} <!-- 8/9/13 -->
{{ today | date:'mediumTime' }} <!-- 12:09:02 PM -->
{{ today | date:'shortTime' }} <!-- 12:09 PM -->

The date formatter also enables us to customize your date format to our own liking. We can combine
and chain together these format options to create one single date format, as well:

Year Formatting

Four-digit year: {{ today | date:'yyyy' }} <!-- 2013 -->
Two-digit padded year: {{ today | date:'yy' }} <!-- 13 -->
One-digit year: {{ today | date:'y' }} <!-- 2013 -->

Month Formatting

Month in year: {{ today | date:'MMMM' }} <!-- August -->
Short month in year: {{ today | date:'MMM' }} <!-- Aug -->
Padded month in year: {{ today | date:'MM' }} <!-- 08 -->
Month in year: {{ today | date:'M' }} <!-- 8 -->

Day Formatting

Padded day in month: {{ today | date:'dd' }} <!-- 09 -->
Day in month: {{ today | date:'d' }} <!-- 9 -->
Day in week: {{ today | date:'EEEE' }} <!-- Thursday -->
Short day in week: {{ today | date:'EEE' }} <!-- Thu -->

Hour Formatting

Padded hour in day: {{ today | date:'HH' }} <!-- 00 -->
Hour in day: {{ today | date:'H' }} <!-- 0 -->
Padded hour in am/pm: {{ today | date:'hh' }} <!-- 12 -->
Hour in am/pm: {{ today | date:'h' }} <!-- 12 -->

Minute Formatting

Padded minute in hour: {{ today | date:'mm' }} <!-- 09 -->
Minute in hour: {{ today | date:'m' }} <!-- 9 -->

Second Formatting

Padded second in minute: {{ today | date:'ss' }} <!-- 02 -->
Second in minute: {{ today | date:'s' }} <!-- 2 -->
Padded millisecond in second: {{ today | date:'.sss' }} <!-- .995 -->

String Formatting

am/pm character: {{ today | date:'a' }} <!-- AM -->
4-digit representation of time zone offset: {{ today | date:'Z' }} <!-- -0700 -->

Some examples of custom date formatting:
{{ today | date:'MMM d, y' }} <!-- Aug 09, 2013 -->
{{ today | date:'EEEE, d, M' }} <!-- Thursday, 9, 8 -->
{{ today | date:'hh:mm:ss.sss' }} <!-- 12:09:02.995 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the module: angular-moment. With this module you will be able to handle your situation similarly to whats below.All you would need to do is have two date variables for you and your users.

```
moment($scope.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Angular v1: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Angular 2: https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach (might be better in your situation) is to add parser and format functions to ngmodelcontroller in the same jqdatepicker directive. Here is the code

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
   return moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}); 

ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
   return moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format("DD-MM-YYYY");
});
```

Here is the plunker created for you to demonstrate the solution https://plnkr.co/edit/7Un2EvTtdigkvo0JJezS?p=preview.